# Configurable product. Qty field for each size(simple product)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

On my product page of configurable product i have sizes(simple products). I need to display qty text field for each size. So customer will be able to add in cart, for example, 4 S sizes or 2 M sizes or 4 S sizes and 2 M sizes. Please give me a link to similar question or solution(would be great). Thank you.